# lodash _.contains one of multiple values in string

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way in lodash to check if a strings contains one of the values from an array?

For example:

```
var text = 'this is some sample text';
var values = ['sample', 'anything'];

_.contains(text, values); // should be true

var values = ['nope', 'no'];
_.contains(text, values); // should be false
```

Comment: You can do this easily without lodash `values.some(el => text.indexOf(el) > -1)` btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution, probably more efficient than looking for every values, can be to create a regular expression from the values.

While iterating through each possible values will imply multiple parsing of the text, with a regular expression, only one is sufficient.

```js
function multiIncludes(text, values){
  var re = new RegExp(values.join('|'));
  return re.test(text);
}

document.write(multiIncludes('this is some sample text',
                             ['sample', 'anything']));
document.write('<br />');
document.write(multiIncludes('this is some sample text',
                             ['nope', 'anything']));
```

**Limitation**
This approach will fail for values containing one of the following characters: `\ ^ $ * + ? . ( ) | { } [ ]` (they are part of the regex syntax).

If this is a possibility, you can use the following function (from sindresorhus's [escape-string-regexp](https://github.com/sindresorhus/escape-string-regexp)) to protect (escape) the relevant values:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

However, if you need to call it for every possible `values`, it is possible that a combination of [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) becomes more efficient (see @Andy and my other answer).

Comment: Yeah I think using a regex is the best option then.

Comment: LOL yeaaahhhh regexps.... guys, someone will have to support your hell after you.

Answer (score 37):

Use [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs#some) and [`_.includes`](https://lodash.com/docs#includes):

```js
var text = 'this is some sample text';
var values = ['sample', 'anything'];

console.log(_.some(values, (el) => _.includes(text, el)));

var values = ['no', 'nope'];

console.log(_.some(values, (el) => _.includes(text, el)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The more modern approach would be to use native JS to achieve the same thing without the need for an external library.

```js
const text = 'this is some sample text';
const values1 = ['sample', 'anything'];
const values2 = ['no', 'nope'];

function test(text, arr) {
  return arr.some(el => {
    return text.includes(el);
  });
}

console.log(test(text, values1));
console.log(test(text, values2));
```

Answer (score 3):

No. But this is easy to implement using [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). [You don't need lodash](https://github.com/cht8687/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore).

Here is a simple function that does just this:

```js
function multiIncludes(text, values){
  return values.some(function(val){
    return text.includes(val);
  });
}

document.write(multiIncludes('this is some sample text',
                             ['sample', 'anything']));
document.write('<br />');
document.write(multiIncludes('this is some sample text',
                             ['nope', 'anything']));
```