# Search array of string using AND in another string using Lodash

Tags: javascript, substring, lodash

I am using lodash to recreate "smart" search which is inspired by datatables smart search.
as mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39989001/4050261

Bellow code is inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37023510/4050261

```js
var text = 'Bhavesh Hingad';
var values = ['Bha', 'Hin'];
console.log(_.some(values, (el) => _.includes(text, el)), text, values);
// Expecting True

var text = 'Bhavesh Jain';
var values = ['Bha', 'Hin'];
console.log(_.some(values, (el) => _.includes(text, el)), text, values);
// Expecting False
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.11.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Currently, the code is performing `OR` bases filtering, I am looking for `AND` based filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Thanks to Google :). Needed to use `every` instead of `some`

```js
var text = 'Bhavesh Hingad';
var values = ['Bha', 'Hin'];
console.log(_.every(values, (el) => _.includes(text, el)), text, values);
// Expecting True

var text = 'Bhavesh Jain';
var values = ['Bha', 'Hin'];
console.log(_.every(values, (el) => _.includes(text, el)), text, values);
// Expecting False
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.11.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need Lodash to use `every()`. It's been native to JS since IE9. If you didn't want to support IE, you could also replace `_.includes()` with the native implementation as well: `values.every(el => text.includes(el));`. Nothing wrong with Lodash - just a note!